# clear on password element does not work with selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am checking validations on login form with Selenium webdriver. The password field does not get cleared with clear. Similar code is working for username field. Am I missing something?

```
it('Password is required', function(done) {
    usernameElem.clear();
    // skipping the test because clearing password field does not work!
    passwordElem.clear();
    loginElem.click();
    driver.findElements(By.className('text-danger')).then(elements => {
      elements.length.should.equal(2);
      elements[1].getText().then(text => {
        text.should.equal('Password is required.');
        done();
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming we are not getting any exception for the line:

```
passwordElem.clear();
```

This should not be necessary, but you can first click on the password field (so it will get focus) and then clear it.

```
passwordElem.click();
passwordElem.clear();
```

You can put a sleep before trying to clear password field.

```
Thread.sleep(3000); // Wait for 3 seconds
```

You can use explicit wait to make sure the password field is ready, before you attempt to clear it.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(passwordElem)).clear();
```

You can confirm once that the password field is enabled and displayed as per the source code of the webpage:

```
System.out.println("Password field is enabled: " + passwordElem.isEnabled());
System.out.println("Password field is displayed: " + passwordElem.isDisplayed());
```

If any of above statement says false, then we will know the reason why the password field is not getting cleared.